# Find shortest path finding all keys

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am struggling with an exercise and was hoping to get some guidance. I build a graph where each vertex is connected to each other vertex with weights. Given a start point A I have to find the shortest path to "collect" all other vertices. One of the issue is that not all paths can be used. This is depending on the already collected vertices.

I have a function "is_path_open(a,b,collected_vertices)" that checks if path from A to B with a given set of collected vertices is open.

I created a hashmap with all connection and its weights i.e (a,b),(a,c),(b,c),(b,a) ...

My intuition is solving it through dynamic programming and memoization. i.e I am looking for the shortest concatenation of these tuples.

Any hints into a possible direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to solve [the travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)?

Comment: This might work. Just need to find out how to incorporate the road block method given that the state might change later. Will give it a go

Comment: just use Dijkstra with states of [currentNode][bitmaskOfVisistedNodes]

Comment: @Photon can you elaborate? I thought Dijkstra needs a start and an end?

Comment: Well start is simple: state: [A][bitmaskWithAOn], for end you can terminate dijkstra as soon as all bitmask nodes are on, dijkstra only needs an end condition adn that counts as one

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! sounds more efficient than TSP

Comment: how would I take paths into account that can be visited given the already collected set of keys in that algorithm?